# Let $R$ be a UFD. Show that if $bc = ax$, then $b \in (a)$ or $c \in (a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $R$ be a UFD. Let $b,c \notin U(R) = R^{\times}$, $b \neq 0 \neq c$ and let $a$ be an
>   irreducible element such that $ax = bc.$ Prove that $b \in (a)$ or $c \in (a)$

My attempt:

**Case 1: $x \notin U(R)$**

$b,c,x$ have irreducible factorisations. Write them out:

$b = p_1 \dots p_n$

$c = q_1 \dots q_m$

$x = r_1 \dots r_l$

Then $$ax = a r_1 \dots r_l = p_1 \dots p_nq_1 \dots q_m = bc$$

and by unicity there exists $u \in U(R)$ such that $p_i = ua $ or $q_j = ua$. Hence, $b \in (a)$ or $c \in (a)$

> Question 1: Is this correct?

**Case 2: $x \in U(R)$**

Here I'm stuck.

> Question 2: Can someone hint me in the right direction?

Comment: Easier way: irreducible is the same thing as prime in a UFD.  Prime means $a$ divides $bc$ implies $a$ divides $b$ or $c$.  Containment $c \in (a)$ means that $a$ divides $c$.

Comment: @D_S you would have to prove first that prime is equivalent to irreducible in a UFD. I guess the OP didn't prove that, hence his approach is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first case is good. For the second, write $a = (x^{-1}b)c$. Then since $a$ is irreducible, either $x^{-1} b$ is a unit, or $c$ is. But then either $b = xc^{-1} a$ or $c = (x^{-1}b)^{-1}a$, and we're done.

Comment: It is given that $c$ is not a unit, hence this can be simplified. This actually helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Thanks for the note.